# Missing seed for metamask -- how can I transfer tokens?

Tags: wallets, metamask

I have lost my seed for metamask wallet. I'm very new to crypto. I have ERC tokens in my wallet, address and password are saved, and the hash generated during transfer is saved. Can I transfer my ERC token from Wallet? It is not open. The problem started during my laptop formatting  andI lost my seed .pl file. Please help me transfer the tokens.

Comment: You may find https://metasafe.org useful

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a copy of your MetaMask backup phrase or wallet passphrase you cannot access your wallet, and thus cannot transfer any ERC20 tokens.
I am sorry this has happened to you, keep a physical copy of your backup's and passphrases next time.